# How can I have a guest session in Ubuntu MATE 18.04?

Tags: mate, guest-session

I know the guest session from the Unity Ubuntu, but I use Ubuntu MATE and I would like to have the guest session activated.

What I mainly want is for all the data in the home folder to be inaccessible, as well as firefox passwords, history and favorites. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. The guest session can be enabled as explained in the duplicate question, but the feature, which previously provided the extra security you ask for, is broken.